# location.reload not getting reloaded

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, reload

when i browse an image i want to show the image at the same time on my web page.for that i had used this code but the image is not showing and when i refresh the page the image is showing and i think my location.reload() function is not working that's why its not working
this is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (){
//alert();
$('#modal-close').click();
$("#file").change(function() { $('#upload-image').submit(); });
$('#upload-image').on('submit',(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
           //alert()
           var formData = new FormData(this);
           $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data:formData,
            cache:false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(result)
           {

                  $('#uploaded-img').html(result);

                  window.location.reload(true);

                }
                });
         }));
```

});

this is my view

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="padding:0px;">
<div class="add-vehcle-image" >
     <form id="uploaded-img"> 

       <!-- added imges contain here  -->
       <?php if($this->session->userdata('image')){
       foreach ($this->session->userdata('image') as $row)
        {?>
          <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 upload-img">
             <img class='img-responsive img-thumbnail' alt='Image' src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/thumb/<?php echo $row; ?>">
                 <div image="<?php echo $row;?>" class="close-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm" >
                     <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title='Delete' class="fa fa-close">
                     </span>
                     <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                 </div>
          </div>
         <?php } } ?>
     </form>


</div>
      <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 24px;">
       <div class="add-vehcle-image">
         <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url();?>admin_control/upload_image" id="upload-image">
          <div class="form-group upload-image">
           <input type="file" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Upload Image" name="file" id="file" >

         </div>
         <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $result->id; ?>" 
         id='product_id'>                
         <input name="table" type="hidden" value="results" id="table">
       </form>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Why would you need to reload the page when using ajax? What do you get in `result`?

Comment: when the page reloads the image will be shown in the page and  the result am getting correctly the problem is image is not displaying while browse an image

Comment: Can you show the result? If there's a link or similar to the image you should not need to reload the page since you can set it with jQuery.

Comment: sorry am new to here,how i will show the result

Comment: Check the result in your browsers console and add it to the question.

Comment: try location.reload() instead of window.location.reload(true)

Comment: i had used that already but didn't get